# PostgreSQL DB with asynchronous npg connection

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql

I have an implementation of an asynchorous notification.

Looking like this:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(ListeningCommand, _npgsqlConnection))
{
     npgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

_npgsqlConnection.Notification += PostgresNotification;
```

NPG 2.x version. I had to set "`SyncNotification=true;`" in the connect string. Everything worked perfect.

With NPG 3.2.5 the connect string does not accept "`SyncNotification=true;`" and the asynchronous behavior does not work anymore.

Any advice how to do this in 3.2.5?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API for notifications has changed from 2.x to 3.2, please read [the documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/wait.html).

Comment: The documentation does not provide info's about SynchNotification. If I use the flag I run in an not supported error message during connection time.
Did somebody successfully use asynchronous behavior with 3.2.5?

Comment: The documentation doesn't provide info about SyncNotification because that parameter no longer exists. Please follow the documentation to receive asynchronous notifications.

Comment: Read the documents again and redesigned according documentation. Now it works. Thanks